# Translate SAS to (Random effect ANOVA)

Tags: r, sas

I'm trying to translate my SAS code for random effect ANOVA to R
here is my code:

```
 proc glm data=A;
 class group;
 model common = group;
 random group;
 run;
```

'group' is group membership, and common is IV.
Please, translate this code into R code.

(edited)

my data looks like this:

```
   id  common    group
    1       4        A
    2       2        A
    3       3        A
    4       2        B
    5       2        B
    6       3        C
    7       4        C
    8       3        C
```

Comment: What did you try so far? How does your data in R looks like?

Comment: please see the edited part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for `lme` and the code can be written as:

```r
library(nlme)

#let's say A (a dataframe) has the sample data
A$group <- as.factor(A$group)

#model
fit <- lme(common ~ group, random = ~ 1 | group, data = A, na.action=T)
```

Comment: I followed your code, and there was an error about missing values. So I changed it to fm2 <- lme(common ~ group, data = A, random = ~ 1, na.action = T). But still it says 'attempt to apply non-function'

Comment: This way group is both fixed and random, that can't be.